# using qtip2 tooltip with d3.js

Tags: jquery, d3.js, tooltip, treemap, qtip2

I'm a d3.js newby and I'm working with a [treemap example](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap/). The original example shows a tooltip when hovering over a specific section. I would like to use a [qtip2](http://qtip2.com/) tooltip instead.

In the d3.js example the following lines are used to add a default tooltip i.e. by setting the *title* attribute:

```
g.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "parent")
    .call(rect)
    .append("title")
    .text(function(d) { return "total: " + formatNumber(d.value); });
```

The qtip2 website suggests the (jQuery) line

```
$('[title]').qtip();
```

would replace the default tooltip with the qtip2 variant. However, it doesn't appear anywhere. Is this the way I should call it?

I was able to produce a qtip2 tooltip by adding a class to the rect elements, like so

```
   g.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "parent")
    .classed({'QTIP2': true})
    .call(rect)
    .append("title")
    .text(function(d) { return "total: " + formatNumber(d.value); });
```

followed by

```
$('rect.QTIP2').qtip({
    content:  'Total number of hits:' + "some value",   
    position: {my: 'center',  at: 'center'},
    style: {width: 75, classes: 'qtip-dark qtip-shadow'},
            show: { effect: function(offset) {$(this).fadeIn(500);}}        
});
```

However, I don't know how to change the "some value" string by the actual d value used in d3.
I'm somewhat familiar with d3.select(this) , datum() and __data__ property, but I was unable to get it working. The line $('rect.QTIP2').text() also produced some results, however, this gave the values for all rects and not just the one you hover over.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$('[title]').qtip();` line wasn't working because it is looking for an element that has a `"title"` *attribute*  (like in HTML), instead of looking for an element that has a child `<title>` element (which is how titles are handled in SVG).  So the selector doesn't return any elements, and no tooltips are created.  As you discovered, so long as your JQuery selector actually returns valid elements, you can get your qtip to work.

To access the data, you're going to need to get into the nitty-gritty.  The d3 data is stored in an element property `__data__`.  The JQuery method to access element properties (which are *not* the same as element attributes) is [`.prop( propertyName )`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/).

So your code would be something like

```
$('rect.QTIP2').qtip({
    content: {
       text: function(event, api) {
                 return  'Total number of hits:' + 
                    formatNumber( $( this ).prop("__data__").value );
              }
       },   
    position: {my: 'center',  at: 'center'},
    style: {width: 75, classes: 'qtip-dark qtip-shadow'},
    show: { effect: function(offset) {$(this).fadeIn(500);}}        
});
```

(Updated: this seems to be the correct way to make the [qtip content](http://qtip2.com/options#content) a function of the individual element triggering it.)

If that's getting confusing, you might want to check out the [d3-tip](http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/) plug-in, which uses the d3 style of `function(d,i){}` callbacks to format the tooltips based on the element data and index.

Comment: Thanks! I tried your suggestion, unfortunately it didn't work :-( With respect to your first suggestion, should I use something like $("rect:has(title)").qtip(); ?

Comment: That should select the rectangles, but I think you should just skip the title text if you're doing custom tooltips -- or add the title as an attribute with d3, and then use [content.title](http://qtip2.com/options#content.title) to make that your tooltip.  P.S.  See updated code for what should hopefully work for grabbing the d3 data directly.